# Check the users position (city, state

Tags: javascript, html, css, location

I was wondering how I can use JavaScript to get a user's location (city or state0 and use the `document.write ("")` to print out the user's location in the window. The location doesn't need to update if the user is moving somewhere it just needs to print out the current location. By location, I mean the state or city that the user is in.

**Note**: I would not like to use google maps or any map to show the users location, I wish to have the user's location printed out on the screen, not on a map.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, that you can only get the position data (e.g. lat and lon). Check out https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp for more information.

If you want to print the state and/or city, you need to rely on a service that resolved the position to a state/city. You can set up an own database for that or you use services like google maps.

Possibly this might be interesting for you as well: https://geolocation-db.com/